# API fetch in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

the screenshots attached are the result of an API fetch (movie database).
From this results, as shown in the screenshots i am trying to reach for the "primaryImage.url" yet I keep on getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url').

Here is my page:

```
const SearchPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const { query } = params;

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(`${rapidApiUrl}/search/title/${query}${rapidSearchData}`, rapidApiOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.results);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [query]);

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((media) => (
          <div key={media.id}>
            {/* <img src={media.primaryImage.url} alt={media.titleText.text} /> */}
            <p>{media.titleText.text}</p>
            <p>{media.releaseYear.year}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

[image: results promise]
[image: the array]

Comment: Clearly on your screenshot - some `primaryImage`s are `null`. So `primaryImage.url` for them will throw an exception. Probalby `primaryImage?.url` will help you.

Comment: Some of the results may not have a url inside the primaryImage object.  add optional chaining to account for this: media?.primaryImage?.url

Comment: The initialState of date should be an Array

Comment: I recomended use the "?" for example "media?.primaryImage?.url

Comment: Because the useEffect first print and after excute the function inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `primaryImage` property appears to be `null` for few cases. You should use `optional chaining` to avoid the errors.

```
return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((media) => (
          <div key={media.id}>
            <img src={media.primaryImage?.url} alt={media.titleText?.text} /> */}
            <p>{media.titleText.text}</p>
            <p>{media.releaseYear.year}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
```

You can read more about `optional chaining` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 2):

As you are looping through the data, some of the primaryImage values are objects, which do indeed have a url property, but some of them are null. When attempting to find the url property of null, it errors out. You probably want to check to see if primaryImage is null and handle it differently than if it has a value.

Comment: Sergey Sosunov, Mark Reed ... you solved it! Thank you so much!!